Remove form from Curl request in perl?
So I'm pretty OK on adding forms to Curl requests in perl like so:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Curl::Form;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

sub chunk { my ($data,$pointer)=@_; ${$pointer}.=$data; return length($data) }
$i=WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$w=$i->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,'https://url/path/');
$i->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, \&chunk );
$i->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, \&chunk );
$i->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, \$headers );
$i->setopt(CURLOPT_FILE, \$body );

my $form = WWW::Curl::Form->new();
$form->formadd('field','value');

$i->setopt( CURLOPT_HTTPPOST(), $form );
my $retcode=$i->perform();

But now I want to reuse the object to post some JSON. Which means I need to clear the form from the request (I'm assuming since I also have the clear the headers and body). What is the correct way to do this? I can't setopt the CURLOPT_HTTPPOST to null because no null and 0 doesn't work either.

I'd just make a new instance.

Re "But now I want to reuse the object", No experience with WWW::Curl, but you'd create a new object with Net::Curl

In the end, I did create a new instance. In the process, I found out I was using the cookiejar wrong so bonus content there.
